# Clarification of the proof of the form $\partial_{1,0}$ in Restrictions on harmonic maps of surfaces by J. Eells and J. C. Wood

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I am currently reading "[Restrictions on harmonic maps of surfaces](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938376900422/pdf?md5=79a360fbd50aeae467c673f9289959b9&pid=1-s2.0-0040938376900422-main.pdf)" by J. Eells and J. C. Wood and have trouble understanding the proof of the lemma on p. 265. The paper states:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be closed orientable smooth surfaces, and $\phi: X \to Y$ a smooth map. Relative to Riemannian metrics $g,h$ on $X,Y$ we say that $\phi$ is harmonic if the divergence of its differential vanishes identically. In isothermal charts, writing $h = \sigma^2(w)dwd\overline{w}$ and representing $\phi$ in the form $z \to w(z)$, that condition is expressed by
> $$
> w_{z\overline{z}} + (2\sigma_w/\sigma)w_z w_\overline{z} = 0,
> $$
> being the Euler-Lagrange equation associated to the energy functional
> $$
> E(\phi) = \frac{1}{2}\int \vert d\phi(x) \vert^2 dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_X \sigma^2(w(z))\left[ \vert w_z \vert^2+ \vert w_\overline{z}\vert^2 \right] dx dy.
> $$
> where subscripts denote partial derivatives and $w_z := \frac{1}{2}(w_x - iw_y), w_\overline{z} := \frac{1}{2}(w_x + iw_y)$, etc.

> We have the complexified tangent bundle $T^c(X) = T(X) \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ and the decomposition $T^c(X) = T^{1,0}(X) \oplus T^{0,1}(X)$ with
> $$
> \partial_{1,0} \phi: T^{1,0}(X) \to T^{1,0}(Y), \quad \partial_{0,1}\phi: T^{1,0}(X) \to T^{0,1}(Y).
> $$
> Let us say that $\partial_{1,0}\phi$ has a zero of infinite order at a point if
> $$
> \partial w/\partial z = o(\vert z \vert^m) \text{ as } z \to 0 \text{ for all } m \geq 0.
> $$
> **Corollary**: If $\phi: X \to Y$ is harmonic but not $\pm$ holomorphic, then neither $\partial_{1,0}\phi$ nor $\partial_{0,1}\phi$ has a zero of infinite order.
> **Lemma**: If $\phi: X \to Y$ is harmonic but not $\pm$ holomorphic, then in isothermal charts $\partial_{1,0}\phi$ and $\partial_{0,1}\phi$ have the forms
> \begin{align}
>     &\partial w/\partial z = Az^m + o(\vert z \vert^m) \text{ for some } m \geq 0 \text{ and complex number } A \neq 0; \nonumber \\
>     &\partial \overline{w}/\partial z = Bz^n + o(\vert z \vert^n) \text{ for some } n \geq 0 \text{ and } B \neq 0.
> \end{align}
> **Proof**: Taylor's expansion to $m^\mathrm{th}$ order for the first gives
> $$
> \partial w/\partial z = Q_m(z,\overline{z}) + R(z,\overline{z}),
> $$
> where $Q_m$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $m \geq 0$, and $R$ is $o(\vert z \vert^m)$ as $z \to 0$.
> The preceding Corollary shows that $Q_m \neq 0$ for some $m$. Substituting the above equation in
> $$
> w_{z\overline{z}} + (2\sigma_w/\sigma)w_z w_{\overline{z}} = 0
> $$
> gives
> $$
> \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}(Q_m + R) + \frac{2\sigma_w}{\sigma}(Q_m + R)\frac{\partial w}{\partial \overline{z}} = 0.
> $$
> Now $\partial Q_m/\partial \overline{z}$ is either a homogeneous polynomial of degree $m - 1$ or is identically $0$. Each of the other terms is $o(\vert z \vert^{m-1})$. It follows that $\partial Q_m/\partial \overline{z} = 0$. Therefore, $Q_m$ is a holomorphic homogeneous polynomial of degree $m$, and consequently has the form $Az^m$. The case $\partial_{0,1}\phi$ is handled similarly.

My main question is: Why is each of the other terms $o(\vert z \vert^{m-1})?$

Comment: You should fix the typo in the definition of $\partial_{0,1}$. To answer your question, doesn't this follow immediately from the fact that $R$ is $o(|z|^m)$?

Comment: Which typo do you mean exactly? The domain and codomain should be correct, no? I am mainly struggling to see why $\frac{2\sigma_w}{\sigma} Q_m \frac{\partial w}{\partial \overline{z}}$ is $o(\vert z \vert^{m-1})$.

Comment: The domain is wrong. Where did the displayed equation come from and what in the world is $\sigma$?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the motivation/origin of the displayed equation and $\sigma$.

Comment: Ok, so $\sigma$ is non-vanishing (not that it matters) and $Q=O(|z|^m)$, hence $o(|z|^{m-1})$. Multiplying by $\partial w/\partial\bar z$ is locally bounded.

Comment: That is exactly the point I don't understand: Why does it follow from $Q_m = O(\vert z \vert^m)$ that the whole expression is $o(\vert z \vert^{m-1})$?